# 'CGRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.width'

Tags: swift, swift4

I'm trying to Test the offset and calculate the current page after scrolling ends.

I just need to update this line to swift 4 ?

```
let pageWidth: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
```

> 'CGRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.width'

```
  //MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate
    override func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
       let pageWidth: CGFloat = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame)
        let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1
        // Change the indicator
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage);

    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> 'CGRectGetWidth' has been replaced by property 'CGRect.width'

`scrollView.frame` returns a CGRect. so you can use the `width` property of the `CGRect`

Like so:

```
scrollView.frame.width
```

This is a simple issue to solve, you should always refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect) first when you are not sure. Here you are trying to get the width of a CGRect, so check the CGRect documentation and see if it has a way to access the size/width.